# how to implement a facebook-like api?

Tags: php, json, facebook, apache, api

i am going to be coding an api, and after playing around with the facebook api, i really like how they do things, especially with the url scheme they use.

for instance, with facebook you can do something like:

http://graph.facebook.com/me/friends

or something like it to get a JSON object of the friends of the user profile.

i know how to so something like that using query strings and whatnot, such as:

http://api.mysite.com/users.php?userid=...&feed=friends

does anyone here know how i can implement something similar to the facebook api with their url scheme?  i really like how it flows (almost has a jQuery-like chainability effect to it).

i looked up the "mod_alias" module to apache, but couldn't determine if that is what i need...

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook is following a RESTful architecture pattern. I recommend you start your research on the same architecture. Here's the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) as a definition.

> Representational State Transfer (REST) is a style of software architecture for distributed hypermedia systems such as the World Wide Web. The term Representational State Transfer was introduced and defined in 2000 by Roy Fielding in his doctoral dissertation. Fielding is one of the principal authors of the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) specification versions 1.0 and 1.1.

Comment: I agree with @justin that "jQuery-like chainability effect" is a much more fun way of putting it than "representational state transfer". :)

Comment: awesome, great start.  i looked into this a little bit, but i guess my question is this:

right now, if i type in:

http://www.mysite.com/profile/username

the server tries to go to the profile/username directory.  instead, i want to treat this as a basic URI and have a script process it rather than point to a directory.

so i guess i am wondering how i can setup a server to serve up a rest api...

Comment: @justin This is as broad of question as "how do I make a website" though, so I wanted to point you to where to start because there are untold number of ways to implement REST. To answer your specific question on how to not have the server try and host the profile/username directory, you'd use rewrite rules to direct them to a php script that can then parse the url string entered. A simple PHP framework that can help you with this is [tonic](http://peej.github.com/tonic/).

Comment: well, i think you led me to my answer.  going through some links i found on the tonic page, i found one about a "front controller" interface.  basically filtering all requests to a script that then branches out to further handle the request as needed.

thanks for the tonic link too, looks like something i might end up needing!